# Writing a reschedulable cron job in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, cron, scheduled-tasks, node-cron

I am using [node-schedule](https://github.com/node-schedule/node-schedule) node package to write the cron job. I am able to write a simple schedular but what I want is a reschedulable job.

In my app, users can start a task for a specific date. Now I can acheive this easily by below code.

```
var schedule = require('node-schedule');
var date = new Date(2012, 11, 21, 5, 30, 0);

var j = schedule.scheduleJob(date, function(){
  console.log('Do something on scheduled date');
});
```

The problem I've is how I can reschedule a selected scheduled job.

Let's say, if **user A** started a job to run on date **10/14/2017** and so I created a new cron job to run on date **10/14/2017**. But now **user A** decides to change the task date to **1/14/2017**, then how would I identify the task created by **user A** out of the multiple tasks already in queue (created by other users) and then reschedule that cron job to the new date i.e. 1/14/2017?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`j` has a `reschedule` method you can call. See https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-schedule#jobreschedulespec.

```
j.reschedule(new Date);
```

To keep track of jobs, you might use an object to map a user to a scheduled job.

```
const userJobs = {};

userJobs['user A'] = schedule.scheduleJob(date, () => {
  console.log('Do something on scheduled date');
  delete userJobs['user A'];
});

userJobs['user A'].reschedule(new Date);
```